# Where to start? Building a website that uses a database

Tags: php, mysql, database, web-applications, web

I haven't started working seriously with web development just at the moment, as I have never had the need for a website. However I am quite competent when it comes to building software using languages like C#, I have also frequently work with Python, so I am not totally in the dark.

When it comes to the web I only know the different languages out there for web development, and have a vague idea of what each one does.
I realize this question could have thousand different answers so I will be a specific as I can.

Here is a description of the kind of website I am trying to build:
Basically a website where users can check out forums, and if they would like to, they can register an account with my website, which would allow them to start posting comments on certain pages.

Basically what I am asking is: In order to start a website, (like the one described above), where do I need to start? What languages/web technologies are going to be needed?, where would the first place be to start? ie. start learning html... Also, is there perhaps any free ebooks online that could get me started.

I hope this is enough information, keep in mind I am not looking for a an incredibly dense and detailed answer, just a simple explanation as to where to start, what language would be simple and easy to start with... I realize to create this kind of website takes a lot of hard work and complicated tasks, so just keep in mind I am only wanting an idea as to how to climb the first 2 or three stairs, not the whole staircase just right now. Thanks heaps!

Comment: Look for CMS ..try FORUM s/w like PHPBB/vBulletin etc Install WAMP/LAMP/XAMPP ..u know python try django

Comment: Please check this link....it has all information as you are expecting.. http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/php/how-to-create-a-phpmysql-powered-forum-from-scratch/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am developing websites on both windows and os x, but as Nick said you will need a PHP + MySQL server which you can get from here:

http://prdownloads.sourceforge.net/appserv/appserv-win32-2.5.10.exe?download

Configuration is fairly easy, however after installing the appserv, I would advise you to download the latest version of PHP from here:

http://windows.php.net/downloads/releases/php-5.4.15-Win32-VC9-x86.zip

and copy all of those files to C:\AppServ\php5. Make sure that apache is not running, you can stop it by going to: Start->All Programs->Appserv->Control Server by Service->Apache Stop.

As nick said it is faster and easier to use forum systems that are already written: PHPBB, vBulletin etc.

Good luck.

Comment: Thank you for this. When you say you develop websites for both Windows and OS X, is there a major difference between how you develop your website for Windows than OS X, ie: I have finished developing the website for Windows, am I now going to have to re-develop the entire website specifically for OS X?

Comment: No, you website will work on windows, os x, linux etc... It doesn't matter what platform you use to create a website, it's just a matter of preference.

Comment: Ok than fair enough, thanks for that. I got a little bit scared for a minute!

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you want forum website, there are lots of ready to use php "platforms" for sites like  this. I personally like "Simple Machines Forum". Other possible solution is "Phorum" and "PHPBB". Google them.

Because you mentioned C#, I am assuming you are working on windows. In order to get this forum up and running you will need PHP and MySQL on your server.

Comment: Thanks for this I will do some research.

Answer (score 0):

What you seek to do is quite complex in PHP but a lot of fun.

Ask yourself, do you really want to do this in PHP or do you want sommething customisable that will produce the end result you desire?

You will get up and running very quickly if you go for something like Drupal which is a fully featured CMS system.  There is a very steep learning curve with any CMS system but you will be able to get what you want going pretty fast.

That having been said, there is a lot to say for developing your site with php as you will learn a lot on the way and you don't have all the overhead of a system that tries to be all things to all people.

I recommend w3schools.com which has excellent tutorials on PHP, Mysql, SQL, HTML and Javascript, all of which will be required to achieve what you need.

The best piece of advice I have ever received on this adventure was 'Design the Project First!' - THINK long and hard about what you plan to do.  Make sure you know what you are trying to achieve for each page and then do them one at a time.

Best of luck!

Comment: Great advice Robert I appreciate it. Clearly put some though into it. Yes it will be a learning curve and a half I reckon, but fun at the same time. Will definitely take this into account!