# How to create a simple web application that interacts with a basic database?

Tags: html, mysql, database

I have to create a few web pages that have forms and I want to search for records in my database or insert records? I have a MySQL server setup and I know a bit of HTML. What steps are needed for my HTML page to run queries and bring back data to display on the html page?

Comment: PHP usually does this (server-side).  ( http://www.w3schools.com/php/php_mysql_connect.asp )

Comment: is PHP something I have to install as an extension for MySQL? Or can I just write PHP and HTML code and it will automatically work with MySQL? I am running Windows, if that helps.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Where to start? Building a website that uses a database](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16768762/where-to-start-building-a-website-that-uses-a-database)

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out, I had to install Apache Web Server and install PHP to get it to work.